# Get Google Sheets ID from local file path in Python

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet whose local path is, say,

```
G:/My Drive/MyFolder/MySheet.gsheet
```

How can I get the ID of the spreadsheet -- the one that appears in its link and can be used to refer to the sheet in Google's Sheets API -- from the local path? I'm using Python with the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't perform operations on local path from your Computer in Sheets API. If you go through the [Comprehensive Guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/), there's no such thing. You can see the available operations in the [reference](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/).